# creating multiple generators from single loop

Tags: python

So, consider the following:

```
iterable1 = (foo.value for foo in foos)
iterable2 = (bar.value(foo) for foo in foos)
```

Since both iterables are creates from same list.. I was wondering if I can generate them together..

like

```
compounded_iter = ( (foo.value,bar.value(foo)) for foo in foos)
```

The above works..

But is it possible to get something like:

```
iter1, iter2 = (......)  but in one shot?
```

I am not able to figure that out..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
compounded_iter = ( (foo.value,bar.value(foo)) for foo in foos)
iter1,iter2 = zip(*compounded_iter)
```

You can, of course, combine those into one line.

Comment: Is there something in itertools that can even make it simpler/easier?

Comment: @Marcin oh probably :P

Comment: @JoranBeasley: citer = ((1,2) for i in range(20) ) and then iter1,iter2 = zip(*citer)  But iter1.next() throws error AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'next'??

Comment: But due to the use of `*` you are not creating iterators here, this is going to consume all the data.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary yeah I know ...I cant really come up with a good way around it .... if i dont consume it then accessing either iter returned would consume the other also ...

Answer (score 1):

```
compounded_iter = ( (foo.value,bar.value(foo)) for foo in foos)
iter1,iter2 = [x[0] for x in compound_iter],[x[1] for x in compound_iter]
```

this would put all the values in iter1, and all the bar.values in iter2

Comment: This isn't what the OP is asking—the question asked whether this can be done all at once (i.e. not in multiple lines).

Comment: I am trying to minimize the looping.. :( This has three for loops.. I am trying to get away with one.. :-/

Comment: you still have twoseparate comprehensions here.